# how to pass username from omniauth to stripe customer create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, stripe-payments

I'm trying to pass the username that is collected from Twitter or facebook when my users get authenticated and created, however a simple (description = user.username) doesn't seem to do it, here's what I've got so far;

```
def self.create_from_omniauth(auth)
create! do |user| 
    user.provider = auth["provider"]
    user.uid = auth["uid"]
    user.username = auth["info"]["nickname"]
    #user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
    user.save!
    if user.save
        Stripe::Customer.create(description = user.username)
    end
    user
   end
end
```

I keep getting the following error, no matter if I use @user.username or even current_user.username.

```
undefined method `each' for "xhtmlit":String
```

Answer (score 0):

I was completely doing it wrong which is why it was spitting out the error for me. The actual code might not be clean but I'm currently working to try and figure out from starting with dirty version to clean version. Here's what I've got so far that works;

```
if user.save
      Stripe::Customer.create(:email => user.username)
end
```

Comment: You'll probably want to move that out of the `if` block. It's going to needlessly hammer the database doing a double save, and it's not doing anything—if `save!` fails, it'll raise an exception and you'll never hit your block. If `save!` succeeds, your if will always evaluate to true.